# Detect Facebook share success?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm looking to detect if a Facebook share on a page was successful, and upon success change the value of a  box. I can handle the latter just fine, but am a little lost as to how execute the actual share detection. I've Google and found FB.ui, but how do I actually implement it into a page and have it run the detection?

Comment: Why do you want to detect it?

Comment: We're going to offer users a discount / special promotion if they complete a share on a product page.

Comment: That is not allowed according to Facebook Platform Policy that you can read https://developers.facebook.com/policy . So save your time and your page will not get banned from Facebook

Comment: I see nothing there saying it's forbidden, do you have a specific part of the policy that I'm not seeing?

Comment: 4.5: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions. (Effective November 5th, 2014, you may no longer incentivize people to like your app's Page)."

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but what we're doing should actually be fine until Nov, at which time we'll just take the promotion down :)

Comment: No it will not. That is for page likes in page tab apps if you have an old app. If you have a new app or are not on a page tab app or doing shares you can not do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you must include Facebook sdk.js library to use all its methods (ideally right after the opening of body tag)

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

The problem with your http://jsfiddle.net/ysdp60cz/ is the scope of the **facebookShare** var. So, in this example, just include it in the *window* object:

```
window.facebookShare = function( callback ) { [...]
```

I don´t know how are you organizing your code, however, with this changes it must work.

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/benjasHu/3dhq9k21/

Cheers.

Comment: benjasHu, this did the trick. I also made a slight change and put all of the javascript in the footer, except for the initial sdk.js library call which is right after the opening body tag. It works like a charm!

Comment: I'm glad that you made it to work! :) If you think this is a correct answer, please mark it as correct ;) thanks!

Comment: @benjasHu, this is cool. However, I just tested with various combinations and found out 1 combination is not working for me. 

For e.g., when user click on the Share button, it will open up a popup. If user did not already logon to Facebook, it will prompt for user to enter email and password to log in. I realized that if user clicked on the 'X' close icon from the popup, it will detect as facebook share error, which is correct. However, if user clicked on the "Cancel" inside the Facebook form, it will detect as facebook share success.

Please advise how can we handle the "Cancel" button?

Comment: @Withhelds you got solution of above query ? i am facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are using the Facebook SDK to create the Share Dialog, but with SDK you can get the response status with something like this (of course, you must load the facebook script firstly):

```
FB.init({
    appId  : 'your-app-id',
    status : true,
    xfbml  : true,
    version: 'v2.1'
});

var facebookShare = function( callback ) {

    var options = {
        method : 'share',
        href   : 'your-url-to-share'
    }),
        status = '';

    FB.ui(options, function( response ){

        if (response && !response.error_code) {
            status = 'success';
            $.event.trigger('fb-share.success');

        } else {
            status = 'error';
            $.event.trigger('fb-share.error');
        }

        if(callback && typeof callback === "function") {
            callback.call(this, status);
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    });
}
```

And then you can assign the click event to your button to fire the share dialog. After that, call the callback or use the ".on" jQuery method to know the response status:

```
$('your-facebook-share-button').on('click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    facebookShare(function( response ) {
        // simple function callback
        console.log(response);
    });
});

// custom jQuery events
$(document)
    .on('fb-share.success', function( e ) {
        console.log('success events');
    })
    .on('fb-share.error', function( e ) {
        console.log('error events');
    });
```

I have not tested this code, but I think that it would work.

Good luck!

Comment: Going to need a little tweaking, but I think this could help. I appreciate it benjasHu!

Comment: I've tried tweaking, but I'm terribly new w/ Facebook's API and not that greatest with js / jQuery (Yet!).

Does this look like I'm on the right track to you?

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/ysdp60cz/)http://jsfiddle.net/ysdp60cz

Keep in mind I did update the app ID and site url with proper information, the app is public etc.

Comment: From where i can get facebook script