# Sharing to facebook unable to display the exact image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I am doing a facebook sharing using an App ID. I have this included in my page

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Source : [Detect Facebook share success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181457/detect-facebook-share-success)

My coding looked like this http://jsfiddle.net/benjasHu/3dhq9k21/

I manage to share the content to facebook with the correct image when there is only one image. So when I tried to share a page content which having more than 1 image, it seems like the facebook get confuse and the image container is just blank with the title displayed wrong.

The result is something like the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a very useful article explaining about Facebook open graph meta customization. http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript

From my coding, Instead of using this :

```
var options = ({
    method : 'share',
    href   : 'url goes here'
}),
```

I replaced to :

```
var options = ({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
            'og:url': 'url-to-share',
            'og:title': 'title-of-page-to-share',
            'og:description': 'description-of-page-to-share',
            'og:image': 'image-displayed-when-sharing'
        }
    })
}),
```